# Freeze I/O on purpose like a vss snapshot

Tags: sql-server, vss

I want to freeze the I/O of a SQL Server instance like the shadow copy does.

The result should look like this:

```
2020-01-19 23:11:40.90 spid73      I/O is frozen on database prod. No user action is required. However, if I/O is not resumed promptly, you could cancel the backup.

2020-01-19 23:11:57.89 spid73      I/O was resumed on database prod. No user action is required.
```

But I want to decide when the I/O is resumed. I tried it myself with a backup, but it finished too fast.

I want to debug my application during this I/O freeze.

How can I achieve this behavio(u)r?

**Edit - 2020-01-27 10:53**

The purpose is that the SQL Server doesn't accept new connections during this time:

```
Exception:
Class name:    EMSError
Message:       [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
Unit name:     OLEDBAccess
```

Comment: May I know the purpose ?, the request seems strange please note if you do so you would see users complaining.

Comment: @Shanky I clarified my intention.

Comment: The error message is different and needs to be fixed, when are you getting this message

Comment: The error message is a result of the I/O freeze. And that's what I want to fix. I don't know how you do things, but I want to get as close to reality as possible. Sure, I could close the port in the firewall etc. but I want to recreate this scenario.

Comment: I would normally vote to close this question as off-topic, as it is more related to programming and would be better suited for stackoverflow.com. There an answer to the question [Compress-Archive Error: Cannot access the file because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47262949/1820861) was posted as: _A good method to access files being used by another process is by creating snapshots using Volume Shadow Copy Service._ and contains an example using PowerShell.

Comment: "The error message is a result of the I/O freeze" that sounds unlikely.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - You're right. First the I/O freezes because of db backup and next the whole VM because of a backup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two undocumented DBCC commands you can use for this, on a test system of course.

```
DBCC FREEZE_IO('database_name');
DBCC THAW_IO('database_name')
```

Check out Erik Darling's blog post here, which is where I first heard about these commands: [Wait Stats When VSS Snaps Are Slow](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/08/wait-stats-when-vss-snaps-are-slow/)

He's also using them to diagnose what behavior is like during these snapshot-related freezes.